# How to filter selector results by data attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show all users in

```
<div id="users>
    <div class="item" data-username="ity">ity</div>
    <div class="item" data-username="ity2">ity2</div>
    <div class="item" data-username="ity3">ity3</div>
    <div class="item" data-username="hello">hello</div>
</div>
```

My idea is simply to show/hide items whose data contains an username

ex: I want to show ALL divs that contains `it` so it should show 3 divs.

I tried with

```
$("div .item[data-username='it']").show();
```

The problem is it affects ONLY `div` elements whose `data-username` IS `ity`.

I also tried `:contains`

```
$("div .item[data-username:contains('it')]")
```

This is not good since it looks for the WHOLE div and not `data-username` ONLY 
the 4th div will be shown as well since it contains "item" inside

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'attribute contains' selector:

```
$("div .item[data-username*='it']").show();
```

Or the 'attribute begins with' selector, depending on your requirements:

```
$("div .item[data-username^='it']").show();
```

Also note that `filter()` can be used too, although this will be slower than the above methods:

```
$('div .item').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('username').indexOf('it') != -1;
}).show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it is a typo but your id "users" is not closed making the html invalid.

You could use some regex style selectors as below

```
$('div.item[data-username^="it"]')
```